# Unable to set cookies in vercel deployment

Tags: cookies, vercel

I have deployed mern project on vercel , frontend url is rahul-social.vercel.app and backend url is social-back.vercel.app , cookies are not being set when I deployed but in development everything works fine. Following is the code for setting cookies

`res.cookie('accessCookie', token, { withCredentials: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: values.time, secure: true })`

Any help is appreciated , may be I am doing something wrong?

My whole project is cookies based and it won't work without cookies and I don't want to store cookies in local storage.